Laptop clock speed stuck at 0.40 only when on battery
my laptop clock speed is stuck at 0.40 ghz when it is on battery. I have tried to set power settings to high performance mode but to no avail. Can anyone suggest me possible fixes? Drivers, BIOS is upto date. Laptop model is Asus x415JF.

Welcome to Superuser. We needs specifics in order to understand your specific situation. Use the EDIT button and add the SPECIFIC things you have done, as well as any specific messages or symptoms you have seen. Also, where are you seeing this clock speed?

In Windows 10, there are settings within each plan.

Open Power Options Control Panel.
Select Change plan settings.
Select Change advanced power settings.



Expand Processor power management and adjust Maximum processor state for use On battery.


As mentioned, i have already put it to 100%, BUT STILL ON BATTERY Power it is stuck

No, you did not state that in the question -- only that you picked "high perfoimance mode*.
